# Formating a txt file

Tags: php, file, strsplit, txt

I have a TXT file formatting that looks like:

```
123451234512345
123451234512345
```

I want to format the file with php in this format:.

```
12345-12345-12345
12345-12345-12345
```

This is what I have tried:

```
$codes = "codes.txt";
$unformatedCode = file($codes, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$abcd = "-";
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $text = (string)$unformatedCode;
    $arr = str_split($text, "");
    $formatedCode = implode("-", $arr);
    echo $formatedCode;
}
```

Comment: What happens with this code? What should happen?

Comment: The second argument to [`str_split()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) is an integer, not a string, and denotes the length of the chunks. So use `5` instead of `""`. In future questions you should include an example of what your code _actually_ does so we don't have to guess.

Comment: Oh sorry my bad i missed it, but iit just return NULL

Comment: In PHP < 8 this would also have generated a warning, turn `error_reporting` on/up. In >= 8 it's throws a TypeError.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
<?php
$arr = array_map(
  fn($v) => implode('-', str_split($v, 5)), 
  file("codes.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES)
);

print_r($arr);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 12345-12345-12345
    [1] => 12345-12345-12345
)
```

If you want to echo the result then do `<?= implode(PHP_EOL, $arr) ?>`

Comment: Thank you sir (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ',' or ') is in my erorlog

Comment: you need upto date php, else change it to a `function($v){return implode('-', str_split($v, 5))}`

Answer (score 0):

Possible that if can be written shorter

```php
$codes = "codes.txt";
$array = file($codes, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$p = "/([1-9]{5})([1-9]{5})([1-9]{5})/i";
$r = "${1}-${2}-${3}";

foreach ($array as $a) {
    echo preg_replace($p, $r, $a);
}
```